# SqlBulkCopy can be used to retrieve the data to in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, stored-procedures

I just want to get the data from SQL Server. Is it possible to retrieve the data from `SqlBulkCopy`.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is far too broad a question as it stands. You need to be far more specific for your individual needs if you want an answer to this one.

Comment: actually, I have a Linq query to retrieve the data as it is very slow. So i was trying to making it fast. So my question is can I do this using SqlBulkCopy?

Comment: Your LINQ query is probably inefficient. You should think about optimising that first. SqlBulkCopy is not going to magically speed things up. If you post the actual query that your LINQ generates we may be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/single-bulk-copy-operations

this may give you some support

Comment: I was asking for Select, not for the insert.